# The Tweet This button drops punctuation that is perfectly tweetable

Tags: bug, status-completed, twitter, url-encoding

I just tweeted a link to this question [What is the best C++ interview question?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25836/what-is-the-best-c-interview-question) and the content had the two + signs (for C++) replaced with spaces. I edited it back to + signs, but I don't see why it should do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aha, correct, this was a bug

```
var url = 'http://twitter.com/share?url=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + 
          '&ref=twitbtn&text=' + encodeURIComponent(message);
```

versus

```
var url = 'http://twitter.com/share?url=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + 
          '&ref=twitbtn&text=' + escape(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign (+) just needs to be encoded before it's sent to Twitter.

So the part that's this:

```
What%20is%20the%20best%20C++%20interview%20question%3F
```

should ideally, if we're wanting to double-plus the face (which itself isn't on the question's URL), be this:

```
What%20is%20the%20best%20C%2B%2B%20interview%20question%3F
```

Twitter just interprets the plus signs as a space because [that's the shorthand](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html#z5).

So it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and/or [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) depending on if that plus sign will ever be encoded before being sent.

Comment: I'm not worried about the URL, but the actual content of the tweet.

Comment: The URL sent to Twitter (which creates the tweet content) is causing Twitter to interpret the ++ as spacespace @kat